# How to use SQLite in HTML file in Windows Embedded 2013

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sqlite, windows-ce

I downloaded the SQLite for WinCE 2013 and I added them the catalog of my sdk.
I don't know how to use SQLite in an html file (using ASP as script language server-side).
I tried the following code:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = JSCRIPT %>
<HTML>
<BODY>

<BR>
<BR>
This is another string
<%
var dbaseConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connect");
var connectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=/SSD/prova.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;";
dbaseConnection.Open(connectionString);


%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The instruction var dbaseConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connect"); doesn't work: if I connect to my device with my web-browser I receive "Automation server can't create object".
What's wrong? Have I to include something?

Thank you

Comment: It seems like the WCE image (not the SDK) is missing somethnig. Did you include from the catalog all required item to let the web server run ASP? Did you create also the OS image?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't know exactly what're the items to include so I included the Web server (HTTPD) with Web Server ASP interface, Active Server Page (ASP) Support and Internet Server Application Programming Interface Administration. I can't find any web page that specify which are the item to include...

Comment: Hello Luca, it seems you have included a reasonable set of item from the catalog. And I understand that you create the image and deployed it to your device, right? Something is missing yet: ADODB item for example? Did you try to run a page with a basilar ASP instruction? Did it works?